# Javascript : form validation , checking an URL

Tags: javascript, html, preg-match

below is the simple form validation code , that alerts user when no value is entered.

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("please enter value");
  return false;
  }
}
</script> 

<form name="myForm" action="hi.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
value: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

What i want is , User must paste **https://www.games.com/#gamer=AAACiF5ZCZCq123** or **http://www.games.com/#gamer=AAACiF5ZCZCqFIBAJdzJmg** in Value field, where AAACiF5ZCZCq123 is the dynamic content , that changes.

So if the user pastes https://www.games.com/#gamer=*something* it should return true,,,else it should return false.

Anyone can give code or idea please.

Comment: hey zerkms , sorry i am noob in javascript can you give explanation?

Comment: they just cant paste /www.games.com/ they should paste /www.games.com/#gamer=

Comment: "So if the user pastes `https://www.games.com/#gamer=something` it should return true,,,else it should return false.". If they paste `www.games.com/#gamer=` - then according yo **your requrements** it should return false. "can you give explanation" --- have you tried to google? Or is being a newbie justifies your laziness?

Comment: I googled...they just given how to get check if url is pasted ,, what i want is #gamer= .....an url with/#gamer= is wat i need

Comment: yes, and `.indexOf` is answer to your original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var checkForm=string.indexOf("https://www.games.com/#gamer=");
```

where the variable `string` is the input the user put in from the index field.
if `checkForm` is -1, then you know that the text "https://www.games.com/#gamer=" was not put in. If it gives anything other than that (most likely 0 since that is where the string starts), then you know that the user correctly inputted the data.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp for more information on the `.indexof()` javascript command.